# Problema com React e Redux

Tags: javascript, react

Olá... estou estudando o React e agora com Redux. Estou tentando fazer um simples exemplo: Onde tenho um input e button, quero digitar um valor no input e ao clicar no botão pegar o valor e somar 1.

Eu consegui fazer:

- Clicando no botão pegar o valor e exibir em outro lugar.
- Clicando no botão pegar o valor inicial e somar 1.

Mas quero digitar o valor e ao clicar somar 1;

Tenho o seguinte código:

type.js

```
export const CLICK_BOTAO = 'CLICK_BOTAO',
             DIGITAR_VALOR = 'DIGITAR_VALOR';
```

actions.js

```
import {
     CLICK_BOTAO,
     DIGITAR_VALOR
 } from './types';

const _valor = (valor) => {
    let s =0;
    let t =parseFloat( s + valor)
    return t;
};

export const clickBotao = value => ({
    type: CLICK_BOTAO,
    novoValor: _valor(value)
});

export const digitarValor = ev => ({
    type: DIGITAR_VALOR,
    novoValor: ev.target.value
});
```

index.js reducers

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import clientesReducer from './clientesReducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    click: clientesReducer
})

export default rootReducer;
```

clientesReducers.js

```
import {
    CLICK_BOTAO,
    DIGITAR_VALOR
} from '../actions/types';

const inicial = {
    novoValor: 0
}

export default (state =  inicial, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case CLICK_BOTAO:
            return {
                ...state,
                novoValor: action.novoValor
            };

        case DIGITAR_VALOR:
            return {
                ...state,
                novoValor: action.novoValor
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

Aplicacao.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import * as actions from "../actions/index";

class Aplicacao extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      inputValue: 0
    };
  }

  inputChange = event => {
    this.setState({
      inputValue: this.props.digitarValor(this.props.novoValor) 
    }, ()=>{
      console.log(this.state.inputValue);
    });
  };

  soma = () => {
    this.setState({
      inputValue: this.state.inputValue + 1
    }, () => {
          this.props.clickBotao(this.state.inputValue)
          console.log(`--- ${this.state.inputValue}`);
    }
    );

  }

  render() {
    const { novoValor, digitarValor: onChange } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="App" style={{ padding: "20px" }}>
        <input
          onChange={onChange}
          type="text"
          value={novoValor}
        />
        <button onClick={this.soma}>
          Clique aqui
        </button>
        <h1>{novoValor}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  novoValor: state.click.novoValor
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  actions
)(Aplicacao);
```

O que deve alterar para ter o resultado que quero?

Comment: Você quer que some o valor 1 ao click ou quer que some o valor do que foi digitado?

Comment: não tenho certeza, mas tente passar o valor direto ao invés de ev.target.value pra sua action. Na verdade se for analisar, caso vc queira que só some o valor digitado, nem precisa da action de DIGITAR_VALOR. Deixe apenas que o sua action de click do botão pegue o valor do event.target.value dentro do componente mesmo.

Comment: Só clicando eu consegui fazer e já esta somando... só que sempre começa do 0 ai clico 1 - 2 -3 .... Eu quero digitar o valor no input e somar exemplo: Digitar 10 e clicar ai ele pega o 10  + 1 = 11 e ai 12 - 13 - 14.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fala Alex, beleza? Cara, eu fiz o código e anexei no GitHub para facilitar tua vida. Esse é o link (https://github.com/victorhermes/SomarNumerosReact)

Uma dica que te dou quando for desenvolver, é colar os arquivos relacionados com o redux (actions, reducers, sagas e arquivos de configuração) tudo dentro de uma pasta store, assim ficando mais organizado. Voltando para o teu código, a única coisa que fiz foi exportar a função, chamar o switch junto ao case SOMAR, copiar todo o state com spread operator do ES6 (que seria o ...state), chamar o estado inicial (quer seria o number dentro do INITIAL_STATE) e colocar o novo valor que vem pela action (no caso, action.payload.number), por fim, colocar + 1 para fazer a soma. Um detalhe importante é usar o parseInt() para transformar o número de string para inteiro.

O resultado final fica assim:
[image: Resultado final]

E acrescentando o increment do javascript, conseguimos o resultado abaixo. Que além de apenas somar, a cada clique, faz um increment de mais 1.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Espero que o código resolva o seu problema :)

Comment: Só complementando o Victor, essa questão de colocar tudo relacionado ao Redux (actions, reducers e types) em uma pasta é um conceito chamado DuckPattern. #VivaBootcamp

Comment: Cara funcionou.... deixa te falar... onde você mora? Porque vou acampar na porta da sua casa, pra ver se aprendo essa bagaça... estou tomando uma surra... rsrs. Agora, gostei da dica de colocar os arquivos dentro da mesma pasta como você fez. Eu estou seguindo alguns tutoriais e o pessoal coloca separado então fiz igual. Agora uma dúvida você não utilizou o arquivo type.js? E muito obrigado pelo trabalho para sanar minha dúvida.

Comment: Kkkkk. Cara, que legal que deu certo. Fico feliz. Então, tu pode usar com o type também. Esse conceito que usei se chama Duck Pattern (Como o Daniel Obara comentou) e nada mais é do que colocar as actions, types e reducers em um único arquivo. Isso serve para aplicações maiores, porque quando fazemos aplicações que são grandes, tem vários types, actions e reducers e ficam vários arquivos, dificultando a manutenção e legibilidade do código. Para minimizar o problema, a gente junta tudo isso e vira esse tal de Duck Pattern.

Comment: Recomendo assistir os vídeos da Rocketseat... que na minha opinião são referencia nacional de conteúdo JS. Segue link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q-If9n-tUyA

Comment: Olá Daniel já sou inscrito nesse canal... já assistir alguns vídeos me clareou muito. Estou pensando em fazer um curso na Udemy. Conhece? Sabe outro online bom?

Answer (score 2):

Fala Alex, beleza?
Cara, esse tipo de alteração é melhor feito dentro do reducer. Ficaria algo mais ou menos assim:

**Actions**

```js
import {
     CLICK_BOTAO,
     DIGITAR_VALOR
 } from './types';

// Alterei sua Action aqui e retirei a função de somar valor
export const clickBotao = value => ({
    type: CLICK_BOTAO,
    payload: { value }
});

export const digitarValor = ev => ({
    type: DIGITAR_VALOR,
    novoValor: ev.target.value
});
```

**clientesReducers.js**

```js
import {
    CLICK_BOTAO,
    DIGITAR_VALOR
} from '../actions/types';

const inicial = {
    novoValor: 0
}

export default (state =  inicial, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case CLICK_BOTAO:
            return {
                ...state,
                // Vamos transformar o value em INT
                novoValor: state.novoValor + parseInt(action.payload.value, 0)
            };

        case DIGITAR_VALOR:
            return {
                ...state,
                novoValor: action.novoValor
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

Veja aí se funciona e dá um toque aí.

Comment: Olá... cara não funcionou. Agora esta ficando assim digito no campo input 10 e quando clico me retorna 010 e a cada clique adiciona 10 assim: 010101010.... ou seja esta concatenando e não somando

Comment: e se tentar converter antes de somar?

Comment: Daniel... não entendi

Comment: Converter o valor para float aqui novoValor: state.novoValor + action.payload.value. Só uma suposição...

Comment: Vou atualizar a resposta lá. Está indo string ao invés de Int.